# How to extract images from doc (not docx) file on linux

Tags: linux, image, doc

I have tried to unzip it like docx files but it doesn't extract images

```
unzip ПерепелкинСергійМихайлович.doc
Archive:  ПерепелкинСергійМихайлович.doc
warning [ПерепелкинСергійМихайлович.doc]:  3599092 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
  inflating: [Content_Types].xml
  inflating: _rels/.rels
  inflating: theme/theme/themeManager.xml
  inflating: theme/theme/theme1.xml
  inflating: theme/theme/_rels/themeManager.xml.rels
```

What command should I use?